# Do amp pages load normal html5 ads?

Tags: ads, amp-html, adsense

There was a report last year that google's amp ad inventory got a 11x increase, but its still around 12% of the total available [link to google blog](https://blog.google/products/ads/making-display-ads-safer-faster-and-better/). I would like to know if amp pages only use amp ads or also the html5 ads ? And if it doesnt, does using **AMP Only** site with amp being the primary and only framework limit my chances of serving the most performing ads. Thanks.

Comment: There is one site I know of which does this way, [axios.com](https://www.axios.com)

Answer (score 0):

AMP pages can get non-AMP ads. Though performance of AMP ads is better (they require less bandwidth and CPU) and more likely to get selected - non-AMP html5 ads are served as well.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Do u have any source for this ?

Comment: No, I don't think there is public info around it. But as you mentioned it AMP coverage of ads is nowhere near 100% so doing AMP-only ad serving is pretty bad from revenue point of view.